# Modify custom attribute value before place order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have a custom attribute that is placed in the Billing Address section. Now there's a condition that I only need to save the first 200 character of my custom attribute text box. Is there an event or observer that will intercept this request before proceeding to save/place order? So basically on the checkout page after inputting the text in my custom attribute when user click the `Place Order` button I want to check this input first if it's beyond the limit then I will trim the text. How do I do this?

Update:

When I tried to intercept the request under `Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface` I was able to view the `personal_message` custom attribute that I'm looking at. But when I try to save or change the value it didn't allow me. How can I override it?

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface">
    <plugin name="validate-billing-information" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\BillingValidation"/>
</type>
```

And this is the code I was trying to overwrite

```
public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
        $cartId,
        $email,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
   $billingAddress->setPersonalMessage("This is an overwritten message");
   $billingAddress->save();
}
```

But doing this throws an error of

```
webapi-5f6f60228b3a3; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homestead_goodgifts`.`quote_address`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ADDRESS_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't call save in your plugin, just edit billing address property, and original savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder will take care of saving. Lastly, don't forget to check billingAddress is not empty! Some code is allowed to call this API without billing address, and your plugin will break things.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the `sales_order_place_before` event.

Here is an example:

```
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderAddressRepositoryInterface;

class [ObserverName] implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $orderAddressRepository;

    public function __construct(OrderAddressRepositoryInterface $orderAddressRepository)
    {
        $this->orderAddressRepository = $orderAddressRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        if ($billingAddress) {
            $[yourCustomAttributeName] = $billingAddress->getCustomAttribute('[your_custom_attribute_name]');
            if (!empty($[yourCustomAttributeName]) && count($[yourCustomAttributeName]) > 200) {
                $[yourCustomAttributeName] = substr($[yourCustomAttributeName], 0, 200);
                $billingAddress->setCustomAttribute('your_custom_attribute_name', $[yourCustomAttributeName]);
                $this->orderAddressRepository->save($billingAddress);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`[updated answer]`

Try observing the `checkout_submit_before`.

```
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [ObserverName] implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
        if ($billingAddress) {
            $personalMessage = $billingAddress->getCustomAttribute('personal_message');
            if (!empty($personalMessage) && count($personalMessage) > 200) {
                $personalMessage = substr($personalMessage, 0, 200);
                $billingAddress->setCustomAttribute('personal_message', $personalMessage);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I can't see the custom attributes that is inside the billing address. When I check the parameters sent in v1/guestt/{id}/payment-informatttion the customattributes is inside the billing address but when I access this using the function above it didn't work

Comment: could you please share what are the items displayed when you hit the API?

Comment: Sure thing dude this is the screenshot of the request and payload I want to modify. Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question @Rendy

Comment: @MadzQuestioning that's quote address, not order address. To get quote address, you should observe `checkout_submit_all_after`. I will update above answer.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning updated the answer by observing `checkout_submit_all_before` event.

Comment: This didn't work as well... The first one sales_order_place_before is being called but when I changed to the second observer it didn't even trigger it

Comment: @MadzQuestioning sorry, it should be `checkout_submit_before`, without `all`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for this.. It work I was able to get the Parameter but the problem is the saving or updating of it. I had to modify the code you gave me and used `$billingAddress->getPersonalMessage()` to get the personalMessage. But when I try to update it didn't work. I tried $billingAddress->setPersonalMessage("My new Message") or $billingAddress->setCustomAttributes('personal_message', "my new message") but none work.. I also tried adding $billingAddress->save() at the end but no luck.. Any idea please?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning try `$billingAddress->setCustomAttribute('personal_message', 'new message')`. `setCustomAttribute` in singular, without additional s.

Comment: Already tried this as well... I'm really frustrated with this error. Although when I tried setPersonalMessage it does change the attribute in the billingAddress but when the process succeeded it still retain the old value